# Averaging a list in Python, "Type Error: Cannot perform reduce with flexible type"

Tags: python, numpy

The code below is supposed to do as follows:

1. Fill an empty list with a specific column of numbers from a csv file.
2. The average of the list values is then calculated and the resulting value is plotted.

Problems: I keep getting the error "TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type". All I do know is that it has to do something with condensing down a list. But I'm not sure beyond that. Any help is appreciated.

```
import csv 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

channelData = []

channelSel = int(input("Select a channel to view "))

with open('PrivateData.csv', newline='') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        channelData.append(row[channelSel])

averagemV = np.mean(channelData)

plt.plot(averagemV) 
plt.ylabel("Average mV")
plt.xlabel("Channel " + str(channelSel))
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the type of each element in `channelData`?

Comment: @Kevin integer. The 5th line of code you can see that it's a user input read as an integer.

Comment: Looks to me like the error is coming from the numpy package, you may want to add that tag.

Comment: But you're not appending `channelSel` to `channelData`, you're appending `row[channelSel]`, which might not necessarily have the same type as `channelSel`.

Comment: @Kevin the values I'm working with are technically float values. row[channelSel] really means take the [channelSel]th value in each row of the csv file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('PrivateData.csv', newline='') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        channelData.append(row[channelSel])
```

I suspect that this is adding strings that look like floats to `channelData`, rather than actual floats. Try explicitly converting.

```
with open('PrivateData.csv', newline='') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        channelData.append(float(row[channelSel]))
```

Comment: Exactly the problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, `numpy.genfromtxt` allows you to read the entire file into a 2d array and with a couple of changes achieve the same result.

`data.txt`:

> ```
> 1,2,3,4
> 5,6,7,8
> 9,10,11,12
> 13,14,15,16
> ```

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    a = np.genfromtxt(f, delimiter=',')

>>> a
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.],
       [  9.,  10.,  11.,  12.],
       [ 13.,  14.,  15.,  16.]])
>>> channelSel = 1
>>> mean = a.mean(axis = 0)
>>> mean
array([  7.,   8.,   9.,  10.])
>>> averagemV = mean[channelSel]
>>> averagemV
8.0
>>>
```